# Creating Dependencies Only to be able to Unit Test

Tags: java, dependency-injection, junit4, dependency-management

I just created a `Manager` that deals with a `SuperClass` that is extended all over the code base and registered with some sort of `SuperClassManager` (`SCM`).

Now I would like to test my `Manager` that is aware of only the `SuperClass`. I tried to create a concrete `SCM`, however, that depends on a third party library and therefore I failed to do that in my jUnit test. Now the option is to mock all instances of this `SCM`.

All is good until now, however, when my `Manager` deals with the `SCM`, it returns children of the `SuperClass` that my `Manager` does not know or care about. Nevertheless, the identities of these children are **vital** for my tests (for equality, etc.).

Since I cannot use the concrete `SCM`, I have to mock the results of calls to the appropriate functions of the `SCM`, however, this means that my tests and (indirectly) my `Manager` need to know and care about the children of the `SuperClass`.

Checking the code base, there does not seem to be a more appropriate location for my test (that already maintains the appropriate real dependencies).

**Is it worth it** to introduce unnecessary dependencies for the sake of unit testing?

---

**Update 18/DEC/2012**

---

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
package some.package.declaration;

import some.open.source.framework.TopComponent;
import some.open.source.framework.WindowManager;

/**
 * Own source code.
 * Knows WindowManager and TopComponent; but no
 * direct child of TopComponent.
 */
class TopComponentManager{

  /**
   *
   */
  void efficientlyDoOperationsOnCurrentTopComponents(){
    Set<TopComponent> currentTopComponents = get all current TopComponents from WindowManager;
    Set<TopComponent> getNeededTopComponents(currentTopComponents);
    do some operations on the current TopComponents;
    ...
    ...
  }

  void Set<TopComponent> getNeededTopComponents(Set<TopComponent> givenTopComponents){
    Set<TopComponent> neededTopComponents = new HashSet<TopComponent>(givenTopComponents);
    disregard and keep some TopComponents based on controls;
    return neededTopComponents;
  }

}

package some.package.declaration.test;   // same project as TopComponentManager

import jmockit;
import some.open.source.framework.TopComponent;
import some.open.source.framework.WindowManager;

import own.source.code.childrenOfTopComponent.ChildTopComponent;  // Don't want to; need to introduce package dependencies
import own.source.code.childrenOfTopComponent.AnotherChildTopComponent;  // Don't want to; need to introduce package dependencies

class TopComponentManagerTest{

  @Tested
  TopComponentManager _topComponentManager;
  @Mocked
  WindowManager _windowManager;
  @Mocked
  ChildTopComponent _childTopComponent1;  //extends TopComponent; unknown to both TopComponentManager and TopComponentManagerTest
  @Mocked
  AnotherChildTopComponent _childTopComponent2;  //extends TopComponent; unknown to both TopComponentManager and TopComponentManagerTest

  Set<TopComponent> _currentTopComponents = new HashSet<TopComponent>();

  @Before
  void setUp() throws Exception {
    _currentTopComponents.add(_childTopComponent1);
    _currentTopComponents.add(_childTopComponent2);
  }

  void testgetNeededTopComponents(){

    Deencapsulation.invoke(_topComponentManager, "getNeededTopComponents", _currentTopComponents);

    new Verifications(){{
      verify that only _childTopComponent2 is returned;
    }};

  }

}
```

As can be seen, while testing the TopComponentManager, I have to verify the determined necessary elements which are unknown at this package.

Comment: > Is it worth it to introduce unnecessary dependencies for the sake of
> unit testing?

For many people it is worth it. At least that is what Maven **test** scope was created for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by creating a new project that only contained my test class. This test class had dependencies to the `TopComponentManager` and all the child `TopComponent`s that were spread around the code base. However, the dependencies are not a matter of concern.

With this approach more tests can be implemented within this project that will not create any additional dependencies on production code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just mock `TopComponent` directly?

Example:

```
@Mocked
TopComponent _childTopComponent1;
```

Comment: I endorse this. Unless you check for the type of the TopComponent with instanceof, then I see no reason not to mock it. If you happen to do this, then perhaps you should think of moving that logic to another component.

Comment: @TomVerelst @Koraktor I cannot do this; as I have said, while testing the `getNeededTopComponents` I need to verify the identities of the TopComponents depending on different situations (when `givenTopComponents` is different). Unfortunately, the example is rather simplified but different TopComponents have different IDs (as constants) and only these constants are accessed by the `TopComponentManager`. The "controls" within the `getNeededTopComponents` method works with them (the IDs).

Comment: @arin: Maybe I didn't understand that correctly, but you should have no problem to verify equality of a mock, even if it is mocked from a super class (maybe even abstract or an interface).

Comment: @Koraktor understood, however, what I need is to verify the identity of a *child* of a `TopComponent` (which you are suggesting I mock here). I need to test that `TopComponentManager`returns me a set containing `AnotherChildTopComponent`, but neither my test nor my manager are aware of this child of `TopComponent`. I can only test for this identity if my test is aware of it, hence my need to introduce the dependency.

Comment: @arin If your test really needs to ensure that your `TopComponent` is a (specific) instance of `AnotherChildTopComponent` than I fear your design is flawed. One the other hand, I don't see a reason why really need to check for the class of the resulting `TopComponent` instance. Object is usually enough and this works for mocks too.

Comment: @Koraktor I don't understand why it is necessarily a bad design; the `TopComponentManager` is not aware of the children and does operations with the help of polymorphism. I am just testing the output of `getNeededTopComponents`. Further, I don't understand what you mean by "Object is usually enough [for equality checks I suppose]". Maybe I am missing something fundamental here or the design is flawed (I wouldn't be surprised nor am I insulted by that; not my design :)).

Comment: @arin: For equality checks, yes. That part of the sentence seems to got missing. What I'm trying to say is that you don't need some specific subclass instance to check whether your `TopComponentManager` is doing the right thing with subclasses. When it's not aware of the subclasses it can't do anything sublass specific and so working with a super class mock *will work*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what your are looking for but [Mockito provide a way to return mocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_MOCKS) when a method of a mock is called:

```
SCM scmMock = Mockito.mock(SCM.class, Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS);
// scmMock.someMethod() will return a mock
```

Comment: thanks, but what I need is the returned mock to be of a certain type. The type is impossible to introduce into the test class without creating a dependency. I hope I understand your answer; if I do, this will not be able to help as the mocked return type must be the type I need, hence the type must be known.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you could give use some code, then it would be easier to give you an answer.

Also, how do you call the `SuperClassManager` when `Manager` is only aware of `SuperClass`? Is it a dependency inside the `SuperClass`? If that's the case, then `SuperClass` has a wrong dependency and you should consider removing this from `SuperClass`.

But if your manager is not aware of the `SCM`, but only of the `SuperClass`, then you should mock the `SuperClass` because the test of the `Manager` must not be dependent on code of other components and you should not create unnecessary dependencies.